# almost sure convergence and convergence of expectation implies convergence in expectation

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, probability-limit-theorems

IF $X_n \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}}X$ and $\mathbf{E}[X_n] \rightarrow \mathbf{E}[X]  $ does this imply $\mathbf{E}[|X_n - X|] \rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Will's answer above shows, the answer is no in general, but if you also assume that all of the $X_n$ are non-negative, then the answer is yes.  Proof: apply Fatou's lemma to $X_n + X - |X_n - X|$.

Comment: Yes, Agreed. I guess then we could just argue $\lim\mathbf{E}[|X_n|] = \mathbf{E}[|X|]$ and be done with it Since everything is positive

Answer (score 2):

No.

For instance let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and for all $n\in\mathbb N^*$ let $X_n$ be defined by
$$
X_n=-n²1_{\{U<\frac1n\}}+n^21_{\{U>1-\frac1n\}}.
$$

Then $X_n\underset{n\to+\infty}{\overset{\textrm{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}}0$ and $\mathbb E[X_n]=0\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb E[0]$ but $\mathbb E[\vert X_n-0\vert]=2n\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$.

Comment: Okay.. So can we then say that for the example that you gave that $X_n$ is not dominated by any random variable, right??

Comment: Yes, $X_n$ cannot be dominated by an integrable random variable independent of $n$, otherwise it would contradict the dominated convergence theorem.